# Spinner functionality not working on Android 6.0.1

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am using `Spinner` for displaying some values. And the strange issue is that

> The **dropdown** is displaying correctly, but when I select any item from dropdown, is not displayed in the box.

And the strange thing is this functionality is working on all Android Operating Systems `before 6.0.1(i.e. 6.0.0 and previous)`.
I have also tried `AppCompatSpinner` and the result is same.

**main.xml:**

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.3"
    android:entries="@array/values" />
```

**Main.java:**

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
spinner.setSelection(5); // Not displaying 5th item, Yes! there are more than 5 items.
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        spinner.setSelection(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        spinner.setSelection(5);
    }
});
```

Comment: I tested your code under two nexus 5 (6.0.0 and 6.0.1) and I was not able to reproduce your problem. Do your array/values contains special characters ? (I just tested with word like zero, one... six, seven). Are you using a particular phone ?

Comment: Its nexus 5 (OS 6.0.1)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's weird that I am answering my own question. But after doing lots of research finally I found a solution.

**Solution:**

There is nothing wrong in the code that I previously wrote.
It's just issue of inner padding in **Android OS 6.0.1**

> In the release of **Android OS 6.0.1** they made some changes in inner padding of a `Spinner`.

After reading this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34316074/3110234) on SO I adjusted my `Spinner` width and made it visible in all the Android OS versions.