# Spinner in Marshamllow has another size

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have an application where I'm using Spinner. After update my testing device to Android 6.0 Marshmallow I found out that my spinners have some additional padding as you can see in the picture:

[image: Spinner in Marsmallow]

But in Lollipop and older version of Android is:

[image: Spinner in Lollipop and in older versions of Android]

As you can see, in the first picture is displaced a text of selected item and arrow.

Is there a way to have Lollipop Spinner on Marsmallow?

Comment: Are both the images from the same device?

Comment: Yes, it's Nexus 5. First picture is from making screenshots for Google Play. The second is from today.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34316074/spinner-inner-padding-is-larger-on-android-6-0-1

Comment: check your layout xml - set margin 0 and padding 0 where these are no needed

Comment: In XML I haven't set some padding and margin...